# Problema al actualizar mi código de una lambda docker

Tags: python, docker, aws, lambda

Tengo una lambda docker que al primer push va como si nada, pero al ahora de hacer el update con

aws lambda update-function-code 
--function-name inference-lambda-docker-01 
--image-uri arn:aws:lambda:us-east...etc.

Me manda a volar y me aparece este error:

Unknown options: --image-uri, arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2...etc.

Según es porque no existe el repo del container en el ecr, pero lo veo en mi cuenta e hice push... wth?

Answer (score 0):

La ejecución de la lambdas basadas en ECR tienen una peculiaridad y es que los permisos de acceso al repositorio de ECR no se los tienes que dar a la lambda sino que tienes que actuar en el repositorio.

Si vas al repositorio ECR donde tienes la imagen, verás que hay un apartado para editar los permisos de dicho repositorio. Ahí tienes que añadir una política *Allow* que permita el acceso de tu lambda a dicho repositorio.

Si este permiso no existe, la lambda no podrá cargar la imagen docker.

Entiendo que este permiso es así de raro porque en este punto no se está ejecutando el código de la lambda. Este permiso actua durante la fase de provisión de recursos, es decir, cuando aws lanza una máquina para ejecutar tu lambda. Esa máquina realmente aún no es tu lambda, luego no se ve afectada por los roles que le hayas dado a tu lambda.

Entiendo que este es el mecanismo que se les ocurrió para que la instancia que se lanza pueda descargar la imagen ECR que tu lambda necesita.

Comment: En Amazon ECR/Repositories/inference02/Permissions tengo: 

Actions
ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
ecr:BatchGetImage
ecr:CompleteLayerUpload
ecr:CreateRepository
ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy
ecr:DescribeImages
ecr:DescribeRepositories
ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy
ecr:InitiateLayerUpload
ecr:ListImages
ecr:PutImage
ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy
ecr:UploadLayerPart
Conditions
{
    "StringLike": {
        "aws:sourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:781211160608:function:*"
    }
}

Aún no me funciona? Me podrías recomendar un ejemplo de policy?

Comment: Pero curiosamente me sale otro error este: "An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: Source image 781211160608.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/inference02 is not valid. Provide a valid source image." al aplicar el comando: "aws lambda update-function-code --function-name inference-lambda-docker-01 --image-uri 781211160608.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/inference02"

Comment: La imagen debe hacer referencia también a la etiqueta de la versión que vas a usar. No será que te falta justamente eso?